# CSS styles rendering differently in .Net

Tags: asp.net, css

This is more of a curiosity question than anything else but if anyone has a suggestion as to what I'm doing incorrectly, if anything, it would be great.

I am using drag and drop ui with objects that are very CSS intensive. I usually create the objects in an html page, apply the html structure, styles, images, etc... until I have the complete object. Then I copy the styles to the .css file and the html images etc.. to their respective directories.

When I run the .Net solution the objects render completely out of whack from what looked real nice in the html page.  Then I need to clean it up and change the styling so the objects look correct in the .aspx/.ascx pages.

I've noticed this behavior in IE8 and IE9. Why does the .css render differently?

Thanks.

Comment: .NET doesn't render CSS. Your browser does.

Comment: What @Jan said.  .NET may be running on your server, but all it's doing is serving up some HTML/CSS and sending it to the browser.

Comment: If you can show us a sample that recreates this issue, we can point out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

IE has many, *many* well-known CSS quirks, and the ASP.NET development environment uses IE8's rendering engine. So, the solution is to code cross-browser-compatibly.